# How to specify two columns from 'in' statement with sql?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have a query I would like to write out:

```
select busnumber from bus where busnumber in 
(select frombusnumber, tobusnumber from transformer where transformernumber = 1 or transformernumber = 1);
```

However, the "select frombusnumber, tobusnumber from transformer" is giving me issues. I understand that I can write this twice with an OR statement and specify each column:

```
select busnumber from bus where busnumber in
(select frombusnumber from transformer where tobusnumber = 1 or frombusnumber = 1)
or busnumber in (select tobusnumber from transformer where frombusnumber = 1 or tobusnumber = 1);
```

However I would like to know if this is the only way to accomplish this task in the situation that I need to merge together a large number of column results together in order to avoid a slew of OR statements.

Comment: I have corrected my answer and will post an explanation shortly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **union** operator to combine the result-set of two or more SELECT statements. for example:

select busnumber from bus where busnumber in
(
 select frombusnumber from transformer where frombusnumber = 1
 **union**
 select tobusnumber from transformer where tobusnumber = 1
)

Answer (score 0):

I think the most efficient method might be:

```
select b.busnumber
from bus b
where b.busnumber = 1 or
      b.busnumber in (select t.frombusnumber from transformer t where t.tobusnumber = 1) or
      b.busnumber in (select t.tobusnumber from transformer t where t.frombusnumber = 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following...

```
SELECT busnumber
FROM busnumber
WHERE busnumber IN ( SELECT frombusnumber
                     FROM transformer
                     WHERE transformernumber = 1
                     UNION
                     SELECT tobusnumber
                     FROM transformer
                     WHERE transformernumber = 1 );
```

With your `IN` statement you will need to compare a single field to the list of bus numbers `WHERE transformernumber = 1`.  Thus the list should be a single column of bus numbers.

This list is formed simply by joining the list of `frombusnumber`s to the list of `tobusnumber`s using the `UNION` operator.  This is known as a vertical join - the more familiar `JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, etc. are types of horizontal joins.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

*Further Reading*

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are interested in 'busnumber' which you can get in 'transformer' table directly.
We can get the result using following query.

```
Select distinct(case
when tobusnumber = 1 then frombusnumber
when frombusnumber = 1 then tobusnumber
end )as busnum
from transformer  where tobusnumber = 1 or frombusnumber = 1;
```

If you remove where clause you will get null values.
You should have provided table structure for better understanding.